# Access index row/column of boolean matrix if True

Tags: python, arrays, vector, filter

I have two vectors (1D array) or different sizes. I want to compute the distance (here the difference) between each point of them, i.e. the difference between the first point of my long vector `l` with each point of my short vector `v`, the same for the second point of my long vector, etc.

I would like to store the result in a `[len(l), len(l)-len(v)+1]` array (called `d`). To do so, i was thinking to use a filter matrix (this is not mandatory).

```
import numpy
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
v = [1, 2, 3, 4]
nc, nr = len(l)-len(v)+1, len(l) # n_col, n_rows
x = numpy.array([[i-j for j in range(nc)] for i in range(nr)])
filter = ((x >= 0) & (x < len(v)))
d = numpy.zeros((nr, nc))
```

So my `filter` matrix is:

```
[[ True False False False False False False]
 [ True  True False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False False False]
 [False  True  True  True  True False False]
 [False False  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False False  True  True  True  True]
 [False False False False  True  True  True]
 [False False False False False  True  True]
 [False False False False False False  True]]
```

Where `True` values represents the non-zeros values i expect.
I can change the values of `d` according to the filter (e.g: `d[filter] = 2`), however i did not succeed to find a way to called the x-th point of `l`, neither the y-th point of `v`.

NB: I noticed that `x[filter]` returns `[0 1 0 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 3 2 3]`, which are the index i would like to call for `v`. But `v[x[filter]]` returns an error (`TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index`)

Any help on how to access the index of row/column where `filter` is `True` or another solution (with or without the filter matrix) would be appreciate.

Output should be:

```
  [[ l[0]-v[0] 0        0         0         0         0         0]
   [ l[1]-v[1] l[1]-v[0] 0         0         0         0         0]
   [ l[2]-v[2] l[2]-v[1] l[2]-v[0] 0         0         0         0]
   [ l[3]-v[3] l[3]-v[2] l[3]-v[1] l[3]-v[0] 0         0         0]
   [ 0         l[4]-v[2] l[4]-v[2] l[4]-v[1] l[4]-v[0] 0         0]
   [ 0          0        l[5]-v[3] l[5]-v[2] l[5]-v[1] l[5]-v[0] 0]
   [ 0          0         0        l[6]-v[3] l[6]-v[2] l[6]-v[1] l[6]-v[0]]
   [ 0          0         0         0        l[7]-v[3] l[7]-v[2] l[7]-v[1]]
   [ 0          0         0         0         0        l[8]-v[3] l[8]-v[5]]
   [ 0          0         0         0         0         0        l[9]-v[3]]]
```

Comment: What's your desired output for your input example?

Comment: Use `numpy.where`

Comment: @Allen, i added the output at the end of the question. @MaxNoe, I don't see how to use `numpy.where` in this case, can you give more details please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Allen's answers, i managed to get the desired output.

```
arr = numpy.asarray(l) - numpy.asarray(v)[:,None]
for i in range(d.shape[1]):
    d[i:i+len(v),i] = numpy.diagonal(arr[:,i:i+len(v)])
```

which returns:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  2.  3.  4.  5.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  4.  5.  6.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  5.  6.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  6.]]
```

This code is unfortunately far from optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your desired output, i.e the pairwise distance between v and l?

```
np.asarray(v)[:,None] - np.asarray(l)
Out[679]: 
array([[ 0, -1, -2, ..., -7, -8, -9],
       [ 1,  0, -1, ..., -6, -7, -8],
       [ 2,  1,  0, ..., -5, -6, -7],
       [ 3,  2,  1, ..., -4, -5, -6]])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I still need the diagonal-block matrix shape in order to be able to use this result as part of a bigger algorithm. So if you have any idea for that too, it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Does this match your desired output?

```
x*filter
Out[710]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 3, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 3, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 3]])
```

Comment: The shape yes, the values no. For example, last row / last column should be  `l[9]-v[3] = 10-4 = 6` and not `3`